# Add proxy to Perl code

Tags: perl, proxy

i'm trying to add a proxy to my perl code but i'm not sure if this is the right code for it??

```
#!usr/bin/perl

{

use strict;
 use LWP::UserAgent;
use warnings;
 my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5');
 $ua->proxy([qw(http https)] => 'http://100.100.10.100:80');
 my $response = $ua->get("URL_IN_HERE");
 print $response->code,' ', $response->message,"\n";

}
```

Comment: Why are you not sure? Did you run it?

Comment: Yes offcourse not with the proxy in it, but i just wasn't sure if this is the right code for it? :) And i know people over here are verry helpfull so i just wanted to ask it.

Answer (score 1):

In your environnement (maybe `~/.bashrc` or such):

```
export http_proxy=http://100.100.10.100:80
```

In Perl code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use LWP::UserAgent;


my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent(agent => 'Mozilla/5.0');
$ua->env_proxy;
my $response = $ua->get("URL_IN_HERE");
print $response->code,' ', $response->message,"\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

See two examples below to understand how to...

---

If your proxy is running on `127.0.0.1` at port `8080` and it supports `http` and `https`, then add

`$ua->proxy(['http', 'https'], 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/');` to your code.

---

If your proxy is running on `proxy.mydomain.com` at port `80` and it supports `http` and `ftp`, then add

`$ua->proxy(['http', 'ftp'], 'http://proxy.mydomain.com:80/');` to your code.

---

Answer (score 0):

Try using the next code :)

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use warnings;
{
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    $ua->proxy( 'http', "http://127.0.0.1:3128");  #Your proxy
    $ua->default_header("Connection" => "keep-alive");
 $ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.63 Safari/537.31");
 $ua->timeout (10);
 my $response = $ua->get("http://google.com"); #Website
 print $response->code,' ', $response->message,"\n";

}
```